# Styling <a> without href attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to match all links without `href` specified via CSS?

Example:

```
<a>Invalid link</a>
```

I know its possible to match all links with href but I'm just looking for the opposite.

Comment: Note that "invalid" here doesn't mean "invalid HTML", but "invalid hyperlink", meaning it doesn't actually point anywhere.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Either use CSS3's `:not()`:

```css
a:not([href]) {
    /* Styles for anchors without href */
}
```

Or specify a general style for all `a`, and one for `a[href]` to override it for those with the attribute.

```css
a {
    /* Styles for anchors with and without href */
}

a[href] {
    /* Styles for anchors with href, will override the above */
}
```

For the **best** browser support (includes ancient but not quite forgotten browsers), use the [`:link` and `:visited` pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited) instead of the attribute selector (combining both will match the same as `a[href]`):

```css
a {} /* All anchors */
a:link, a:visited {} /* Override */
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet/10589840#10589840) for an in-depth explanation of `a[href]` versus `a:link, a:visited`.