# css doesn't apply on a tags without href attibute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I use SASS, and I styled a tags with this code:

```
a {
color: $col-accent;

&:hover {
    color: $col-alt;
    background-color: $col-accent;
    text-decoration: none;
}}
```

And I have a few `<a>` tags in a page without an `href` attribute, and they aren't styled by this. I just can't figure out why.

I'm using bootstrap, and I saw a rule in the reboot part of it, that inherit color of a tags without href. But I added my own code, which is the same as above, except that I applied it to `a:not([href])`, and it doesn't override bootstrap's, which I imported before my custom css.

Comment: You can use `!important` to override bootstrap styling. It's better not to use it, but in some cases you simply can't avoid.

Comment: to keep css behavior on a tag, keep the href attribute , it can be empty. without an href attribute, it is alike any inline tag and will not react either to focus or active ... On the other side, to overwrite a rue, the selector coming next(your case) must have at least a weight/specifity equal to the the previous : **how to calculate the actual specificity value to determine which selector takes precedence.https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ .**

Comment: Why wouldn't you have href attributes?

Answer (score 0):

```
a:not([href]) {
    /* Styles for anchors without href */
}
```

First answered in :
[Styling <a> without href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128711/styling-a-without-href-attribute)

Comment: The problem is that I DID that. But It's still overwritten by bootstrap's reboot file, even if I import my custom styling after bootstrap's.